# Is there a way for django's ModelForm.is_valid to exclude certain fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a ModelForm with several fields.  Some of them should not be checked when I call form.is_valid().  However, I still want them displayed in the template so I don't think I can exclude them from the form.  Is there a way to overload form.is_valid() to loop through all the fields and only actually validate the ones I care about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick solution without any other research is it overwrite the field's clean method to essentially check nothing. That way when clean is called for that field, validation will pass.

Comment: i am  new to this thing please guide me how to implements this on Child table

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you wish to allow blank fields then you can specify `blank=True` in the the model's class definition.

eg:

```
screen_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
```